# Как сделать переключатель страниц в UNITY С#?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Кратко - начинаю делать текстовую игру , столкнулся с проблемой , не получается сделать переключатель страниц . Например - есть тексты с индексами 0,1,2 ... И две кнопки. При нажатии на одну - включается текст со след индексом , при нажатии на другую - с предыдущим . Желательно объяснить доступнее , если есть такая возможность , потому что ничего не понятно . Вроде как это всё делается с помощью массивов , индексов , но именно реализовать как - непонятно .

Answer (score 2):

У вас есть массив строк. Две кнопки. Текст. На текст вешаете скрипт, наедаем его `showText`

Там делаете массив строк, переменную и функцию:

```
public int currentTextIndex;

public void changeText (string text) {
    GetComponent<Text>().text = text;
}
```

На кнопки вешаете `boxCollder2D` и скрипт:

```
Public GameObject mainText;
private void OnMouseDown () {
    mainText.GetComponent<showText>(). changeText(mainText.GetComponent<showText>().currentTextIndex + 1;
}
```

А для кнопки назад делаете -1. Также проверяйте, чтобы не выйти за границы массива и не перейти, например, на страницу 0 или -1

Comment: Почему нельзя просто сравнить? То есть переходим на 9 страницу, проверяем - в массиве 10 элементов, все норм. 10 - отменяем, так как всего 10 страниц

Comment: @Danis а ты часто видишь закольцованные страницы текста в играх?

Comment: @Yaroslav извините не правильно понял вопрос. да остаток от деления это лишние